# A question about Berkeley's attack on Locke's distinction of primary and secondary qualities

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, locke, berkeley

I'm reading W. T. Jones account of Berkeley's theory, and I find that in general Berkeley convincingly demonstrated some weak points that are fundamental to Locke's theory. But there is one of his particular argument which I don't get the point:

In Jones' book "A History of Western Philosophy Vol 3: Hobbes to Hume", the author first cite a passage for Berkeley original work "A Treatise Concerning the Principles of Human Knowledge":

> They who assert that figure, motion, and the rest of the primary or original qualities do exist without the mind, in unthinking substances, do at the same time acknowledge that colours, sounds, heat, cold, and suchlike secondary qualities, do not; which they tell us are sensations, existing in the mind alone, that depend on and are occasioned by the different size, texture, and motion of the minute particles of matter. . . . Now, if it be certain that those original qualities are inseparably united with the other sensible qualities, and not, even in thought, capable of being abstracted from them, it plainly follows that they exist only in the mind. But I desire any one to reflect, and try whether he can, by any abstraction of thought, conceive the extension and motion of a body without all other sensible qualities. For my own part, I see evidently that it is not in my power to frame an idea of a body extended and moving, but I must withal give it some colour or other sensible quality, which is acknowledged to exist only in the mind. In short, extension, figure. and motion, abstracted from all other qualities, are inconceivable. Where therefore the other sensible qualities are, there must these be also, to wit, in the mind and nowhere else.

Then the author gives his own comment:

> This argument is extremely effective against Locke and Descartes, who held that color, sound, and odor are mind-dependent and yet denied that size and shape are. Strictly speaking, however, the argument shows only that primary and secondary qualities are "inseparably united." Hence those who did not agree with Locke and Descartes that the known facts about physiology "conclusively demonstrated" the mind-dependence of sense qualities would not be touched by this argument as it stands.

My problem is that I fail to see how this particular argument of Berkeley comes to be effective. I my understanding, by mind-depence of secondary qualities Locke doesn't mean these are fabricated by minds, but only that the objects have primary qualities and their primary qualities simultaneously  cause us to perceive primary and secondary qualities. How does pointing out that primary and secondary qualities as perceived by us are "inseparably united" gonna undermine this position of Locke? It seems to me quite irrelevant…

Comment: Here the author's point is that those primary qualities (extension, size, shape) exist only in mind once they're "inseparably united" with the secondary qualities. It's similar and helpful to link Kant's transcendental idealism where the "thing-in-itself" cannot be possibly known to the human mind and is not any perceivable or conceivable primary/secondary qualities per se (limit ordinal metaphor)...

Comment: Our *senses* may be compelled by external  stimuli to invariably perceive secondary qualities along with primary qualities, but our *thought* is not exposed to such stimuli, and hence is not subject to such compulsion. If we cannot separate the latter from the former *even in thought* then the distinction must go by the wayside. And if secondary qualities are acknowledged to be mind-dependent then the same goes for primary qualities.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the clarification, this is really subtle... But I must admit that I'm not convinced by Berkeley's argument that we cannot separate these qualities in thought. Of course we cannot separate them when thinking of concrete object, but when thinking abstractly we can. That's exactly the reason human is capable of mathematical reasoning...

Comment: I agree in part. When Berkeley says "I must withal give it some colour or other sensible quality" he talks about imagining or intuiting a body, not about *conceiving* it (Kant later drew sharp distinction between intuitions and concepts). We can surely conceive colorless bodies just as we can conceive colorless numbers and other abstractions. However, intuition is already sufficient for Berkeley's argument. It is in thought, after all, and is not subject to any sensory compulsion. Inseparability of extension and color even in intuition speaks against their difference in kind.

Comment: @Conifold Well, thanks very much for clarification. Now I kind of understand why Berkeley would say so and why his argument is so influential. But even taking all these subtleties  into consideration, I must admit that the kind of propositions like "if they are inseparable in intuition, they must have same epistemological status" sounds barely plausible to me. I'll be very hesitating to say this proposition is true. Perhaps this is because I'm not familiar with that kind of mindset which contains absolutely clear-cutt metaphysical or epistemological categories like reality, truth, knowledge……

Comment: You have the right idea. That we can understand an argument does not mean that we have to accept it. Berkeley's argument is not airtight. One can imagine, for example, that our intuition is structured so as to reproduce what takes place in the senses, *including* generation of secondary qualities. But this calls for further study to find *independent* reasons to believe that it is so, not just speculation to save a doctrine. In philosophy we talk about plausibility, and supporting or undermining claims, not resolving them conclusively.